# how to separate names using regular expression?

Tags: r, regex

I have a name vector like the following:

```
 vname<-c("T.Lovullo (73-58)","K.Gibson (63-96) and A.Trammell (1-2)","T.La Russa (81-81)","C.Dressen (16-10), B.Swift (32-25) and F.Skaff (40-39)")
```

### Watch out for T.La Russa who has a space in his name

I want to use *str_match* to separate the name. The difficulty here is that some characters contain two names while the other contain only one like the example I gave.
I have write my code but it does not work:

```
str_match_all(ss,"(D[.]D+.+)s(\\(d+-d+\\))(s(and)s(D[.]D+.+)s(\\(d+-d+\\)))?")
```

Comment: It is a rather broad topic unless you precise the context. Names can follow different, various patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,actually I check all the pattern. And I give them here.Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
res <- unlist(strsplit(vname, "(?<=\\))(\\sand\\b\\s)*", perl = TRUE))
res
#[1] "T.Lovullo (73-58)"  "K.Gibson (63-96)"   "A.Trammell (1-2)"   "T.La Russa (81-81)"
```

To get the names only (if that is what the expected)

```
sub("\\s*\\(.*", "", res)
#[1] "T.Lovullo"  "K.Gibson"   "A.Trammell" "T.La Russa"
```

Comment: You do not need a word boundary between a letter and `\s` pattern, it is implicit there.

Comment: Thank you so much!